# German for "Liouvillian extension"

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-algebra, mathematical-german, differential-field

How do I correctly translate "Liouvillian extension" to german, especially "Liouvillian"? "Liouvillsche Erweiterung" sounds rather strange, but might be correct. Anyone knows if this is correct?

Comment: I would say "Liouvillesche Erweiterung" and explain what it is. Strangely enough, Wikipedia does not have a German page for this or differential algebra...By the way, I am German.

Comment: Abelian extension= Abelsche Erweiterung, etc, so why not?

Comment: Actually, it sounds better in German than in English. Without knowing the field at all, I would have said “Liouville extension”.